# Powershell script with a path with square brackets in a string for

Tags: powershell, square-bracket

I can't get my Powershell script to work with a path which has square brackets.

Input path is *"c:\temp\yeah [thats it]"*

```
param (  
    [string]$folderPath = $env:folderPath
 )
$folderPath = $folderPath + "\"

    Add-Content -Path $folderPath"01-playlist.m3u" -Value "a file name.mp3"
```

I looked at '-literalpath' and 'Convert-path' but I can't see how to implement that to my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`.

```
Add-Content -LiteralPath "D:\Test\yeah [thats it]\01-playlist.m3u" -Value "a file name.mp3"
```

Now the path is taken literally, so you cannot use wildcards as you would with `Path`.

By the way, your optional parameter looks strange.. Unless you have set an environment variable for it, there is no such thing as `$env:folderPath`

Also, to combine a path and a filename, there is a cmdlet called [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path). Using that is far better than using constructs like `$folderPath + "\"` where it is very easy to either forget backslashes or adding too many of them..

Instead, I would write

```
$file = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath '01-playlist.m3u'
Add-Content -LiteralPath $file -Value "a file name.mp3"
```

Comment: Illegally easy, thanks!
I will look at join-path.
When I run the script use -folderpath %P (Populated by TotalCmd with current path)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backticks I believe. If you are doing this from a shell this works
````` "abc ````[123````].txt" `````
Note the number of back ticks changes to two if you are wrapping with single quotes.

See this answer: [https://superuser.com/questions/212808/powershell-bug-in-copy-move-rename-when-filename-contains-square-bracket-charac#:~:text=Getting%20PowerShell%20to%20correctly%20recognize,four%20backticks%20to%20escape%20it](https://superuser.com/questions/212808/powershell-bug-in-copy-move-rename-when-filename-contains-square-bracket-charac#:%7E:text=Getting%20PowerShell%20to%20correctly%20recognize,four%20backticks%20to%20escape%20it).